# How to notify all windows that static property has changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have lots of windows and I need to update all ListViews when my static property from App.xaml.cs changes.

App.xaml.cs:

```cs
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private static ObservableCollection<tasks> _AllTasks;

        public static ObservableCollection<tasks> AllTasks
        {
            get => _AllTasks;
            set => _AllTasks = value;
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnStartup(e);

            AllTasks = new ObservableCollection<tasks>(Core.db.tasks.ToList());
        }
    }
```

Adding new task:

```cs
        private void OnAddTaskExecuted(object p)
        {
            tasks tsk = new tasks()
            {
                taskname = "1",
                description = "",
                date = DateTime.Now,
                empID = 2
            };
            Core.db.tasks.Add(tsk);
            Core.db.SaveChanges();
            App.AllTasks = new ObservableCollection<tasks>(Core.db.tasks.ToList());
        }
```

As you can see I'm adding a new task and redefine static field. But I need all my ListViews in different windows to refresh. And I assume that I need PropertyChanged event in set of AllTasks, but I can't add it, cause AllTasks is static.

Comment: Instead of App.AllTasks = new... Add the items to the collections instead: `foreach(var task in Core.db.tasks.ToList())) App.AllTasks.Add(task);`

Comment: And if you need to clear it before adding: `App.AllTasks.Clear();`

Comment: the problem is when i add a new task. It adds, but to see it I need to reopen the window

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else... You are not supposed to create a new observable collection every time. You add and remove items from it. Show us how you bind this collection to your view

Comment: ok, i got thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I don't need to make a new instance of ObservableCollection every time just to refresh it.

I changed `private void OnAddTaskExecuted(object p)`
from `App.AllTasks = new ...`
to `App.AllTasks.Add(tsk);` and it worked.

Thanks so much to @Nawed Nabi Zada